# How does android studio update during runtime work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been developing in Unity environment for a while and I'm wondering how Android updates events during runtime ? In Unity there is an update function that I can use, just wondring the if there is an equivalent function in Android.

Comment: You need to be more clear on what you are asking. What is going to be updating?

Comment: Are asking if there is the ability to see live code updates without rebuilding the entire app?